# ASP.Net Core - How to add a new field to the default Microsoft Identity structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using ASP.Net Core 2.1, I am trying to add a new field to the default Microsoft Identity Users table structure, so I created a new model that I used in the project database context to inherit from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, I used to implement the following code successfully but this time I got error.

Here is the model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the database context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public string CurrentUserId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the output error:

> The non-generic type 'IdentityDbContext' cannot be used with type arguments

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I don't see a base constructor which accepts those 2 type arguments.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn468175(v%3Dvs.108))

Valid type arguments are:

```
//none
public class IdentityDbContext
```

or

```
//application user
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser>
```

or

```
//Thanks to @ Ivvan
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey>
```

or

```
//the full version
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>
```

---

So in your case, I think you meant:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

Comment: It is true for EF6, but there is [extra constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-3?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in EF Core, that accept 3 params: TUser, TRole, TKey. But anyway, OP missed one parameter.

Comment: @Ivvan: thanks for the heads-up... I was lost in the *Forrest of docs*.

Comment: @Ivvan,  just for information, Previously I was using it with 3 params: TUser, TRole, TKey, currently I need only one param, TUser and now it works perfect after I removed the missing Tkey (string).

Comment: @Stefan, Yes, you're right, it was just a stupid error, I copied the code with 3 params and missed to remove the third one: "string", as I don't need roles in my project, now it works fine using:     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>